# Select into temp table syntax error Access Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to insert two columns(`conceptname`, `storeNumberID`) values from `lodgingReport` into `temptable`. But there is a syntax error and I can't find the fix

```vb
db.Execute "Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into" & TempTable & "from TblLodgingReport"
```

Full function (inserted from comments):

```vb
Function CreateTempTable() 
  Dim db As Database 
  Set db = CurrentDb() 
  db.Execute "Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into" & TempTable & _
             "from TblLodgingReport" 
  MsgBox "table is created" 
End Function
```

Comment: You're missing spaces. Add spaces before and after the `"` quotes: `"Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into " & TempTable & " from TblLodgingReport"`

Comment: I tried adding spaces. Still the same error

Comment: Eh... Then you're probably doing something weird like including a space in your table name. Add square brackets: `"Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into [" & TempTable & "] from TblLodgingReport"`

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: Include the full code. There are probably errors elsewhere.

Comment: Here you go                      


Function CreateTempTable()
        Dim db As Database
        
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        db.Execute "Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into" & TempTable & "from TblLodgingReport"
        MsgBox "table is created"
          
End Function

Comment: Eh... You've defined the variable `TempTable` nowhere. Do you just want to do `"Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into [TempTable] from TblLodgingReport"`?

Comment: You did not declare the variable "TempTable" anywhere in the code you listed. That is most likely the problem you are encountering. Basically your code says to run this query : "Select [Concept Name], [Store Number ID] into from TblLodgingReport"

Comment: Should I declare Temptable as variant or as tabledefs?

Comment: Dim TempTable As String

Comment: Even with string, its the same error

Comment: TempTable = "temptable" (the string needs to be setup)

Comment: Its throwing new error. Here is new code: Query input must contain atleast one table or query

 Dim db As Database
        Dim Temptable As String
        Temptable = "temptable"
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        db.Execute "Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into " & Temptable & "from [TblLodgingReport];"
        MsgBox "table is created"

Comment: Looks like the space before "from" is still missing. It should be " from". Right now, the SQL reads : `Select [Concept Name],[Store Number ID] into temptablefrom [TblLodgingReport]`

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you So much

Comment: For future reference: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)